# $A=\frac{xx^T}{x^Tx}$.Find the dimension of the vector space $[y \in \mathbb{R^3}:Ay=0]$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

Let $x \in \mathbb{R^3}$ be a non null vector and $A=\frac{xx^T}{x^Tx}$.Find the dimension of the vector space $[y \in \mathbb{R^3}:Ay=0]$.
Clearly the question asks what is the dimension of the null space of $A$.
We know it is $n-\text{rank(A)}$
So, here we need rank$(A)$.
Now, I just made an observation.
$x^Tx$ is a scalar.
We know $\text{Rank(A)}=\text{Rank}(A^T) = \text{Rank}(x^Tx)=1 $,as it is a scalar.

So, the dimension of the null space of $A=3-1=2$
Am I correct?

Comment: $x^Tx$ might be a scalar, but $xx^T$ isn’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Yet there might be a mistake. You could check that $A^{\top}=A$, especially, $\left(xx^{\top}\right)^{\top}=xx^{\top}$.

Instead, you could make use of the rank inequality, i.e.,
$$
\text{rank}\left(AB\right)\le\min\left\{\text{rank} A,\text{rank}B\right\}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\text{rank}\left(xx^{\top}\right)\le\text{rank}x=1.
$$
Thus as long as $xx^{\top}\ne O$, we have
$$
\text{rank}\left(xx^{\top}\right)=1.
$$
The rest of your proof follows hereafter.

Comment: Yeah,yeah I made a silly mistake..thanks

Comment: @LegendKiller: No problem :-)

Comment: Do you see *why* $xx^T$ has rank 1 OP? It is because every row is a multiple of the same vector $x$.

Comment: @Mike: You are right. This should be a more intuitive way to go for the proof. OP's method was a bit different from this, but it remains viable.

Answer (score 1):

You’re close. The key isn’t that $x^Tx$ is a scalar but that $x^Ty$ is: $Ay = {xx^T\over x^Tx}y = {x^Ty\over x^Tx}x$, so for all $y$, $Ay$ is a scalar multiple of $x$. Since $x\ne0$, this means that the rank of $A$ is one and so the dimension of its null space is $3-1=2$.